# Ping Flooding in router log

Tags: router, ping

I've had recently a period of repeated disconnections from my router with connection problems. I checked my router log I found several Ping Flooding entries all originating from the IP 69.171.227.232 which turned out to be one of Facebook IPs! I'm wondering what does that means? Can Facebook chat cause such a condition?

My router is DLink dir 600 and the condition that devices were disconnected from router, not router from internet.. Connection is WAN

And how to solve this router problem??

My wifi clients were about 3-5 at that time..

Comment: Are you disconnected from your router, or is your router disconnected from the internet?  What make/model is the router, what connectivity (WAN - ADSL etc / LAN - wired, wireless etc).  Click here to add more detail: [edit].

Comment: My router is DLink dir 600 and the condition that devices were disconnected from router, not router from internet..
Connection is WAN

Comment: So it is wireless that is disconnecting?  How many wifi clients do you have and do they all disconnect?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please consider registering an account on this site. You seem to have lost your original cookie that associates your computer/browser with this question, so you weren't able to edit the question just now (your *suggested edit* had to be approved by someone else). You're also unable to respond to comments or comment on answers.

Comment: @Freeman, I've merged your accounts